# Can you return a render() without a context?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django template I'm rendering, however, I have no need to give a context to it (I don't use any variable in the template).

Is it okay if my render/return function looks like this:

```
    return render(request, 'shipment/createAccount.html')
```

This code is functionally working, but I want to make sure there is not a better way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly ok. If we check the declaration of `render`, we see that it returns

```
return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
                        **httpresponse_kwargs)
```

After that, we check the definition of `render_to_string`:

```
def render_to_string(template_name, dictionary=None, context_instance=None):
    -snip-
    if not context_instance:
        return t.render(Context(dictionary))
```

So, obviously, it's ok to not provide a context dictionary. To be sure, we check how `Context` handles a situation when `dictionary=None`:

```
super(Context, self).__init__(dict_)
```

...this is getting deep! We check the base class of `Context`, `BaseContext`, and find that it handles the situation perfectly well:

```
def __init__(self, dict_=None):
        self._reset_dicts(dict_)

    def _reset_dicts(self, value=None):
        builtins = {'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}
        self.dicts = [builtins]
        if value is not None:
            self.dicts.append(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine, but `render_to_response` is the shorter, more "vanilla" version. There's not much magic -- see the actual code in django at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py

The main alternative is if there's no view logic/auth required, you could treat this as a static file instead.